# Deploy Node.js app to AWS elastic beanstalk that contains static assets

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having some trouble visualizing how I should handle static assets with my EB Node.js app. It only deploys whats committed in the git repo when you do `eb deploy` (correct?) but I don't want to commit all our static files. Currently we are uploading to S3 and the app references those (`the.s3.url.com/ourbucket/built.js`), but now that we are setting up dev, staging, and prod envs we can reference `built.js` since there can be up to 3 versions of it.

Also, there's a timespan where the files are uploaded and the app is rolling out and the static assets don't work with the two versions up on the servers (i.e. built.js works with app version 0.0.2 but server one is deploy 0.0.1 and server two is running version 0.0.2)

How do keep track of these mismatches or is there a way to just deploy a static assets to the EB instance directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a deploy script that uploads relevant assets to S3 then perform the Elasticbeanstalk deploy. In that script, upload the S3 assets to a folder with the name of the env, so you'll have

```
the.s3.url.com/ourbucket/production/
the.s3.url.com/ourbucket/staging/
the.s3.url.com/ourbucket/dev/
```

Then you have the issue of old assets during deploy - in general, you should probably be CDNing these assets (I recommend CloudFront because its so easy to integrate once you're already on AWS) and you should be worrying about cache invalidation during deploy anyway. One strategy for dealing with that is to assign an ID to each deploy (either the first 7 letters of the git sha1 or a timestamp) and put all assets in a new folder with that name, then reference that on your HTML pages. So lets say you go with timestamp, and you deploy at 20150204-042501 (that's 4:25 and 1 second UTC on February 4, 2015) so you'd upload your assets to `the.s3.url.com/ourbucket/production/20150204-042501/`. Your HTML would say

```
<script src="//the.s3.url.com/ourbucket/production/20150204-042501/built.js" />
```

That solves both the "during deploy" problem and cache invalidation.

Comment: How would I keep track of what the latest version number is? This is a frontend service so there is no DB it directly talks to (it just talks to REST APIs). I was thinking I'd need a DB just to store the asset versions. Is there another way?

Comment: I'd put a line in the deploy script before packaging up the code to write a file called version.txt which is just one line with the timestamp or git hash. Upload the code to Elastic Beanstalk with the version.txt file. When your Node server is starting up, make sure it reads that file to get the string before it listens to a port to make sure it doesn't serve requests without it. Keep that value in a variable and never read from that file again.